# How to disable SPINNER real time if any one of RADIOBUTTON is selected and enable it back when not

Tags: android

I have List of `RadioButton` and a `Spinner`. The data for both comes dynamically from `ArrayList`. Now, I want to disable `Spinner (R.id.spinner)` if any one of `RadioButton (R.id.option_image)` is selected and enable if none is selected.

I tried to disable `Spinner` if `RadioButton` was checked in  `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` but that didn't work, may be view was already drawn by then. How can I do this enabling and disabling of component which would update my view immediately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<s>At first, put all radiobuttons to radiogroup and use `if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {}` to detect, that any radiobutton is selected OR you can put all radiobuttons to `ArrayList` and use `.isChecked()` in for each loop. In past, use `.notifyDataSetChanged()` if you're using adapter. Unfortunately, right now i haven't PC, so I will write a complete solution later.</s>

Try this:

```
ArrayList<RadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...

    final Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    radioButtons.add(findViewById(R.id.radio1));
    radioButtons.add(findViewById(R.id.radio2));
    radioButtons.add(findViewById(R.id.radio3));
    radioButtons.add(findViewById(R.id.radio4));

    for (RadioButton radioButton : radioButtons) {
        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                spinner.setEnabled(!isChecked());
                //if you are using listview with adapter:
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    //...
}

private boolean isChecked(){
    for (RadioButton radioButton : radioButtons) {
        if(radioButton.isChecked()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```